# How can I restructure a JS object?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of appointments structured like so (taken from JSON format):

```
var oData = {
    "data": {
        "d": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "Room": "403",
                    "Title": "MaLyssa Scott Meeting",
                    "Category": "Meeting",
                    "EventDate": "2016-10-31T19:30:00Z",
                    "EndDate": "2016-10-31T21:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "Room": "403",
                    "Title": "OF Upgrade Meeting",
                    "Category": "Meeting",
                    "EventDate": "2016-10-13T17:00:00Z",
                    "EndDate": "2016-10-13T18:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "Room": "428",
                    "Title": "IPAC DTID CRM",
                    "Category": "Meeting",
                    "EventDate": "2016-10-12T17:30:00Z",
                    "EndDate": "2016-10-12T18:30:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "Room": "434",
                    "Title": "BPR-12-001 Updates",
                    "Category": "Meeting",
                    "EventDate": "2016-10-10T15:00:00Z",
                    "EndDate": "2016-10-10T15:30:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "Room": "436",
                    "Title": "OF Update Meeting",
                    "Category": "Work hours",
                    "EventDate": "2016-10-12T17:00:00Z",
                    "EndDate": "2016-10-12T18:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "Room": "454",
                    "Title": "Real Property Meeting",
                    "Category": "Meeting",
                    "EventDate": "2016-10-12T20:00:00Z",
                    "EndDate": "2016-10-12T21:00:00Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to group the results array by Room Number, so for example, Room 403 has 2 children that are siblings of one another rather than 2 separate objects.

I figure I can do this with an 'if' statement and then push the objects into an array for each Room, whats a best practice to perform something like this?

Comment: first, forget the idea of it being "json". what you are restructuring is an object. Secondly, this isn't really a common case (every case of restructuring A to B is different) so there will be no "best practice". just do it then come back when you can't go any further and search for dupes on that particular issue.

Comment: right, thanks for the edit

Comment: Can you ask for a different object from the server? Ideally your server-side database query would return something close to your end state. Right now you are dumping the DB then sorting it, when you can ask for it in sorted form from the database to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce -

```
var newData = oData.data.d.results.reduce(function(prev,curr){
    if (!prev[curr.Room]) { // if room not already in the object add it.
        prev[curr.Room] = [];
    }
    prev[curr.Room].push(curr); 
    return prev;
}, {}); // init with an empty object

console.log(newData);
```