# How can an array containing objects be restructured in a preferred format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given the following example:

```
foobar: [
  {
    "foo": {
      "title": "example title foo"
      "desc": "example description foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "bar": {
      "title": "example title bar",
      "unnecessary": "this is not needed"
      "desc": "example description bar",

    }
  }
]
```

How to format this array containing objects that you get the following result:

```
[
  {"example title foo": "example description foo"}, 
  {"example title bar": "example description bar"}
]
```

Comment: the wanted result is not valid javascript. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: Adjusted it. I've been trying Array.prototype.reduce(). But that doesn't really seem to fit the purpose. Basically I have two types of responses from an API call. I want to restructure the response in such a way that I can use the same function on both. A function that expects a certain format.

Comment: I had a comma instead of a ':'. Seem trivial to the question though, but I've corrected it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to create the desired object

```js
let foobar = [{"foo":{"title":"example title foo","desc":"example description foo"}},{"bar":{"title":"example title bar","unnecessary":"this is not needed","desc":"example description bar"}}]

let output = foobar.map(a => {
  let { title, desc } = Object.values(a)[0];
  return { [title] : desc }
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Ah the map function. Someone in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092378/how-can-i-restructure-a-js-object) also pointed out that a best practice would be to create a better query in the database so you'd get the desired format. However sometimes it's so trivial that I'd like to just restructure the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a single value's object, destructure it and map the wanted style.

```js
var foobar = [{ foo: { title: "example title foo", desc: "example description foo" } }, { bar: { title: "example title bar", unnecessary: "this is not needed", desc: "example description bar" } }],
    pattern = ({ title, desc }) => ({ [title]: desc }),
    result = foobar.map(o => pattern(Object.values(o)[0]));

console.log(result);
```